# Running two IPython instances at the same time

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to run two instances of IPython in Emacs at the same time, one with Python 2, and the other Python 3: is it something doable or there's something in the way `python.el` is designed that would prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, that's possible. Add the following code to your init-file (note that you might have to adapt `/usr/bin/ipython2` and `/usr/bin/ipython` to point to appropriate executables for IPython 2 and IPython 3, respectively):

```el
(defun run-python2 ()
  (interactive)
  "Run IPython with Python 2."
  (let ((python-shell-buffer-name "Python 2"))
    (run-python "/usr/bin/ipython2 -i" nil t)))

(defun run-python3 ()
  "Run IPython with Python 3."
  (interactive)
  (let ((python-shell-buffer-name "Python 3"))
    (run-python "/usr/bin/ipython -i" nil t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-2") 'run-python2)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-3") 'run-python3)
```

With this in place you can launch IPython 2 via <kbd>C-c C-2</kbd> and IPython 3 via <kbd>C-c C-3</kbd>. (You can of course change these bindings to your liking.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well, and will be very useful to me.

Comment: Minor detail: would you happen to also know if it's possible to have different prompt colors for each REPL?

Comment: @cjauvin You're welcome :) As for your follow-up question: I'm pretty sure it's possible to have different prompt colors for each REPL. However, ANSI colors are not my area of expertise... I suggest you ask a separate question about changing prompt colors ("How to change prompt color in Python REPL?"). If someone can outline a general approach, I can certainly help you integrate the solution into `run-python2` and `run-python3`.

Comment: Thanks! I found a simple solution: simply adding `if sys.version_info[0] < 3: c.PromptManager.in_template =  r'{color.Green}In [\#{color.Green}]: '` in my `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.

Comment: @cjauvin That's great -- a non-Emacs solution, but hey, if it gets the job done... ;)